# Which store to use when installing an x509 certificate

Tags: .net, security, ssl, cryptography, x509certificate

Ok, so my app needs to interact with a 3rd party web app that uses client certificates to authenticate the user. (I just need to open a window with a web browser control, and navigate to the site).

The vendor has tossed me 6 .cer files.  One will be a root, I assume that there will be 1 or more intermediate certs, and 1 or more client certs.  No idea which is which.

These will be self-issued certs, so I don't expect for the issuer cert to be trusted by default -- I will need to install the root into trusted publishers.

So, I know that I need to install these certs into my key store, but I don't know which cert goes into which store.  What do I need to do to figure that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are using MS Windows of some sort if you are running some other OS stop reading here :-)

To go the correct way you should do like this:

Root certificate --> Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Intermediate certificate  --> Intermediate Certification Authorities

Client certificate --> Personal.

In my experience you can’t relay on Windows import guide to put the certificates in the right stores you have to tell it in which store to put the certificates.

To sort the certificates you have to make a certificate “chain sort”
Look at all the certificates and sort them in the one or more chains.

Root --> Intermediate --> Second Intermediate --> client.
  |----> Another Intermediate --> another client

When you are sorting the certificates you look at a certificate and which certificate that have signed it. The root is self signed and the first intermediate certificate is signed by the root. The second intermediate certificate is signed by the first intermediate and so on.

Your client certificate should be the only certificate/s that have a private key.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open the certificates by double clicking them using explorer. Check the details and install them in Windows. Check where they go. Then click them to see the certificate chain from that certificate upwards. You can always remove them again. If unsure, use a separate, non-critical install. Note that certificates also contain an *issuer* string, which points to the certificate/private key used to sign the certificate.

Note that for client certificates you need not just a certificate but a private key as well. The normal way to get such a pair is to create a private key and certificate request containing the public key. This you send to the other party. The other party must be sure that the request has originated from you. The other party then creates a certificate belonging to *your* private key. With this pair you can perform client authentication.

An alternative method of performing certificate path verification is using the `openssl verify` command. Note that many certificates are binary/DER encoded. If they are PEM encoded (openssl's main format) then they look like text. If not they probably start with `30` hex, which means they are DER encoded. You need to convert those certificates to PEM format before using the `openssl verify` command. Note that you can simply concatenate the PEM files to create a set of (CA) certificates.

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
openssl verify -CAfile ca-chain.pem certificate.pem
```